# How a modal see the row's index Reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, web

I'm having difficulty on passing the index from button to button so here is my code. Tthe first one is the render loop that shows all my rows and its button the button at the delete part is calling the index from the row.

```
    renderItem(d, i) {
  return <tr key={i} >
    <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
    <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
    <td>{d.Address }</td> 
    <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name, d.Address , d.Department)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td> 

    // this part is calling button is calling the {i} or what we call the index
    <td><center><button className ='btn btn-danger'  onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID , d.Employee_Name,i)} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteEmployee"> Delete</button></center></td>


         </tr>
}
```

this is where it proceed to my modal

```
 {/*Delete*/}
           <div className="modal fade" id="DeleteEmployee" role="dialog">
           <div className="modal-dialog">
             <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 className="modal-title">Delete Employee</h4>
                </div>


                  <div className="container">
                  <div className="modal-body">
                        Are you sure you want to delete {this.state.Employee_Name}?
                  </div>
                  </div>
                <div className="modal-footer"> 
     // I tried calling the index here but the modal can't see my index
                <input type="submit" className ="btn btn-danger"  data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this, this.state.Employee_ID ,this.state.i)}/> 
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

but the onclick on my modal can't see the index, because it always delete the first row

```
deleteEmployee(id, index) {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
    fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/'+ id, {
         method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response) {
     // history.go(0);
      var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
      this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
  });
    this.state.jsonReturnedValue.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({})
}
```

PS: The delete works my problem was only the ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the button you should change it

```
 <td><center><button className ='btn btn-danger'  onClick={this.handleOnclick2.bind (this,d.Employee_ID,d.Employee_Name,i)} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteEmployee"> Delete</button></center></td>
```

and add the bind in your constructor

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { jsonReturnedValue: []}

     this.handleOnclick2= this.handleOnclick2.bind(this)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the emplyee ID into the bind function as a parameter, which doesn't make sense at all, what you need to do is pass the employee ID to the deleteEmployee function, like this:

```
onClick={() => this.deleteEmployee(d.Employee_ID , d.Employee_Name,i).bind(this)}
```

Also just as an extra information start using ES6's awsesome arrow function and you don't have to bind the `this` everytime, for instance in your case just change the above click handler to:

```
onClick={() => this.deleteEmployee(d.Employee_ID , d.Employee_Name,i)}
```

and your `deleteEmployee` function should look like this:

```
deleteEmployee = (id, index) => {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
    fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/'+ id, {
         method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response) {
     // history.go(0);
      var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
      this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
  });
    this.state.jsonReturnedValue.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({})
}
```

Comment: it was working fine before i had the modal.. when it directs to the function

Comment: maybe you have so many `this.setState()` in your delete function,  you should always try to use it just once, in your case try setting the state in after the successful response, in `then`